# scripts to update my database after a payment is made using paypal

Tags: php, paypal

Im haing a problem iv been researching for weeks now on the paypal API but i just can't figer how to do this.

I need there to be a button on my website which then it goes to paypal.

Once you have paid the chosen amount it goes to a php page which updates the database though php.

Comment: Since you've tried for weeks: what have your failed attempts looked like?

Comment: Isn't that described in the PayPal api? And take a look at this: [Paypal + PHP: how to receive a value on success sale](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2223658/1456376).

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn on paypal ipn in your paypal preferences. Once paypal has the money it sends you a transaction back to your server. In the script that accepts the transaction you can have it update your tables.

Documentation : https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/ipnguide.pdf

generally you pass a notify_url parameter with the request, and set up a page which handles and validates IPN notifications, and PayPal will send requests to that page to notify you when payments/refunds/etc. go through. That IPN handler page would then be the correct place to update the database to mark orders as having been paid.

i found a tutorial here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

I found more suitable the [PayPal NVP API](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview) instead of tradional [IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) (Instant Payment Method)

You can find several code examples for PHP (including very similar to your problem and more advanced) in the [library code for NVP samples](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code)

Comment: am not a real good php programmer, on all i did was to add buy now paypal button, on my website i even get email notification after a payment is made but i need how to go to a successful php page which inserts variables from paypal and add only paid amount into my database table

Comment: You can create a form to a specified automatic step. In your Paypal account, click in tab "Merchant Services", and you can create some buttons with vars, but it will only make a POST request in your page, but never to database insertion, that's is up to you, you should program that logic part.